# How to extract certain characters and words in a line, in Unix

Tags: linux, unix

I have following sample output from a grep command.

```
AB/Flow_20210101.log:[20210101_09:30:55] Transaction Id 1234567
BC/Flow_20210101.log:[20210101_09:31:20] Transaction Id 9874567
```

Using the above output, I want to have a extract like below.

```
AB 20210101_09:30:55 1234567
BC 20210101_09:31:20 9874567
```

Comment: You can extract data with `sed`. Try `sed s/^(..).*[(.*)].* ([0-9]*)$/\1 \2 \3/p`

Comment: You can also do it with `awk` by using `/` `[` and `]` as delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in UNIX

```
sed -e 's/\// /' -e 's/\[/ /' -e 's/\]/ /'|cut -d" " -f 1,3,7
```

My output is:

```
AB 20210101_09:30:55 1234567
```